# How to rename web.config transforms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2005, rename, web-config-transform

I am working in an ASP.net MVC 5 solution in Visual Studio 2015. I have the following `web.config`

[image: web config transforms]

How do I rename those to be

- Web.Integration.config
- Web.Staging.config
- Web.Production.config

When I right-click on those, I don't get a rename option!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can copy the files, rename them and manually edit the .csproj file to include them (replacing the generated ones) like below:

```
<Content Include="Web.Integration.config">
   <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
 </Content>
 <Content Include="Web.Staging.config">
   <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
 </Content>
 <Content Include="Web.Production.config">
   <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
 </Content>
```

Unfortunatelly I did not find a way to acomplish this through visual studio.

Comment: make sure to check afterwards in the configuration manager that no projects have been 'unchecked' for build. This can waste a lot of time if you don't notice until later

Answer (score 8):

This is the third time I've set one of these up in a project and I get stuck every time. The key is that the config transform files are linked to the named build configurations.

If you go to `Build` > `Configuration Manager...` and select the `Active solution configuration` drop-down you can add new build names. Afterward you can right-click your web.config and `Add Config Transform`, which asks no questions and just creates one transform for each build.

Renaming an existing build didn't work, it still generated a transform with the original name, but you can delete builds or selectively delete the transform files.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the extension **Configuration Transform** go to **Build > Configuration Manager** and find the **Configuration** dropdown for the project of which you want to change the app config. You can then select the **edit** and rename the build configurations for that project. Then re-run the Configuration Transform tool and it will generate app configs using the names you provided in the build configuration settings.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: doesnt work for renaming just creating new ones, the question is for renaming.

Answer (score 1):

What I found worked for me is to just delete the Debug and Release, and then create new ones. Saved me a lot of worry with dangling references and build errors and the like